# Remove paragraph line behind textbox expanded throughout a page in ms-word

Tags: ms-word, formatting

[image]

I have a textbox that expands all over the page. There is a table in that textbox. I have tried all the wrap text options. The problem is that there is one line on the page that doesnt move to next page. Even if I expand the textbox a bit longer, that line hides behind the textbox. Cutting and pasting that line creates some formatting problems so I want it to move automatically.
How can I make that line to move to nextpage?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is meant to fill the page why is it in a text box? Remove it from the text box and the problem is solved.

Unless the wrap format of a text box is set to "In line with text" it must be on the same page as the paragraph it is anchored to.

Comment: Actually I have to place table at 90 degree. So I am using textbox. And, I am avoiding using "In line with text" option as I have to then shift text during further modification to the file.

Comment: Then your only alternative is to cut and paste the text box into a paragraph that has no text in it.